# Where does the GNU `date` command's nanosecond precision come from?

Tags: time, gnu

The GNU `date` command is one of the few implementations with the ability to return nanoseconds:

```
%N   nanoseconds (000000000..999999999)
```

For example, we can get the number of *nanoseconds* since epoch by combining the `%s` and `%N` symbols.

```
$ date +%s%N
1402513692992913666
```

Now then, to the actual question.  **Where does GNU's `date` command get such a precise representation of time?**

*Note: I'm asking where GNU date is getting its time information from (C calls? `/proc`?), not where the computer itself is (hardware).*

Comment: Note that precision and accuracy are two different things.

Comment: @SLaks I don't know (or care) if it's right.  I'm just wondering where it get's all those digits of precision from.

Answer (score 1):

Use The Source, Luke!  If you look in the source of GNU date, you'll see (in `lib/gettime.c`):

```c
# if defined CLOCK_REALTIME && HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME
  if (clock_gettime (CLOCK_REALTIME, ts) == 0)
    return;
# endif

  {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);
    ts->tv_sec = tv.tv_sec;
    ts->tv_nsec = tv.tv_usec * 1000;
  }
```

So the answer to the question is `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME)` where that's available, and `gettimeofday()` otherwise (multiplying up from microseconds).